# distinctUntilChanged() not working. onNext called on every insert of similar/equal objects

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

```
class Entry(var amount: Double,var name:String): Parcelable{

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
@NonNull
var id: Int = 0

  override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
      val entry = other as Entry
      return (amount == entry.amount)
   }

  override fun hashCode(): Int {
    return 0
   }
 }
```

***********************JAVA representation*******************

```
public class Entry {

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private int id;
private Double amount;
private String name;

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
   Entry entry = (Entry) o;
   return amount==entry.amount;
  }

@Override
public int hashCode() {
 return 0;
  }
}
```

EntryDao class has:

```
@Query("SELECT * from Entry")
fun getAll(): Flowable<List<Entry>>

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insertEntry(entry: Entry)
```

I have subscribed to entry list

```
 entryDao?.getAll()?.distinctUntilChanged()?.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            ?.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            ?.subscribe {list-> updateData() }
```

when i insert 2 equal Entry objects (as per equals and hashCode implementation)

```
entryDao.insert(Entry(10,"Bottle"))
entryDao.insert(Entry(10,"Bottle"))
```

why onNext() is being called on every insert even though the objects are all equal and distinctUntilChanged() is used? Could anyone please explain it.

Comment: `distinctUntilChanged` considers subsequent items for comparison. If you have "ABA", you'll receive all 3. Did you mean to avoid duplicates? Use `distinct()` instead.

Comment: @akarnokd: But in this case i have "AA"  similar objects. I have tried distinct() also. After the second insert, i get a list containing both objects in onNext(). What i need is :-

"oldList "      = listOf( obj1, obj2, obj3)       
"newList" after insert = listOf( obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4)
Is it possible that in onNext() i only get "obj4" instead of the entire list ?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Kotlin. Is `amount: Double` `java.lang.Double`? Is `==` a value comparison or a reference one like in Java?

Comment: entryDao.insert(Entry(10,"Bottle"))
entryDao.insert(Entry(10,"Bottle"))
As per my understanding, i should not get any callback on the second insert because both objects are equal and there are no distinct elements. Am i missing something ?

Comment: What is `getAll` returning? Looks like you insert two entities that get different ids, and thus the first insert triggers a 1 element list and the second insert triggers a 2 element list.

Comment: **getAll()**  is returning the List of "Entry" objects  from the Entry table.
and Yes, two entities with diff id's. But both entities are equal (==).So, what role did **distinctUntilChange/distinct**  operator served here. If i remove this operator then also i get the same result .

Comment: How many `List<Entry>`s do you get from `getAll`? There is a difference between a sequence of `Entry`s and a sequence of `List<Entry>`s. `distinctUntilChanged` compares subsequent objects of a sequence and if they are distinct, the same objects are passed along, regardless what that object logically means.

Comment: I get one List<Entry> from **getAll**  and that list contains all the objects.
**getAll()** in java lang :-  **Flowable<List<Entry>> getAll()**.  So, here i am dealing with **sequence of Entry**s.

Comment: No, you are dealing with a sequence of **list of Entry**s. A sequence of Entries would have the signature `Flowable<Entry>`.

Comment: You are absolutely right !! I am dealing with **sequence of list of Entry**s rather than **sequence of entry**s . I just changed the code and it worked like a charm.
Thank you so much for your time and effort.

Comment: Your Java and Kotlin implementations of `Entry` are not equivalent. In the Java version, `equals` may unexpectedly return false because the `==` operator tests reference equality.